# jquery ui draggable not working in ie9 div margin auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, draggable, margin

I'm a bit frustrated because it's the first time i can't get a code that works in IE7 and IE8 to do the same in IE9.

The problem arose when i tried to center a div inside another div and make the child one draggable and did the usual `text-align:center` for the parent and `margin:auto` for the child.

```css
#center-menu-container {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 880px;
    z-index: 100; /*IE7 fix to lay above image map*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

and the child div

```css
#levelmenu {
    margin: auto;
    width: 150px; 
}
```

I've managed to reproduce the issue in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtMxc/). Just comment line 23 of the css panel to 
have it draggable.